# LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean instantiation not finding persistenceunit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have the following LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean

```
@Bean
public static LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean fakeEntityManagerFactory(){
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    MergingPersistenceUnitManager persistenceManager = new MergingPersistenceUnitManager();
    persistenceManager.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath*:META-INF/fake/persistence.xml");
    bean.setPersistenceUnitManager(persistenceManager);
    bean.setPersistenceUnitName("fake");
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter= new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
    bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    return bean;
}
```

The Persistence.xml contains the following:

```
<persistence-unit name="fake" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>fake</jta-data-source>
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
</persistence-unit>
```

however when it sets the persistenceUnitName (bean.setPersistenceUnitName("fake");)

I get the exception

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No persistence unit with name 'fake' found
```

I believe this is because the bean hasn't yet loaded the persistence units when it is being set.

How can this be resolved?

**Edit:**

I read that .setPersistenceUnitName shouldn't be used if setting the persistenceUnitManager : (taken from official docs)

```
NOTE: Only applied if no external PersistenceUnitManager specified.
```

However If i remove it, it results in an :  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/fake/persistence.xml}`

Comment: Do you really need the `persistence.xml`? Also wondering why is your `@Bean` method static generally you don't want those to be static?

Comment: static is just autogenerated. And i'm converting from xml to annotations, so an alternative is just fine

Comment: What is that is generating that?! The only `static` `@Bean` methods should be the ones that register `BeanFactoryPostProcessors` like a `PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer`. But I would just ditch the `persistence.xml`. Also instead of setting the `persistenceUnitManager` property you could simply try setting the `persistenceXmlLocation` on the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory`.

Comment: I'm also wondering why are you creating the bean yourself? Judging by the tags you are using Spring Boot then let Boot do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: I need to use my own Persistence Manager for multiple persistences since this is merging multiple projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem with MergingPersistenceUnitManager.
My solution worked with spring boot 2.0.3

```
    persistenceManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos();
    persistenceManager.setDefaultDataSource(dataSource);
```

Without setting dataSource is not possible to start transaction.
You don't need to set persistentUnitName in code.